# Subtract Duplicates between 2 Arrays

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Say I have column A which contains 20 unique alphabetical names, and column B which contains 5 alphabetical names. I want to write a formula that counts the unique names in column A and subtracts matching names that exist in column B. For example, if I have A2 = Tom, A3 = Mike, A4 = Ben, A5 = Sam; B2 = Ben then it takes 4 unique names from column A and subtracts the 1 matching name in column B to equal 3. I also want this formula to ignore blank cells across both column ranges.

Comment: Have you already tried something? What stops you to write the formula that you are describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B:B, A:A)), LEN(A:A)))))
```

[image: 0]